# Working in Iran for foreign company

Tags: salary, working-abroad

I'm Iranian and as you know we are under sanctions. I'm a computer programmer. Can I work for a company (for example in US, UK or Germany) and earn my income while staying in Iran?

Is it possible to transfer my income to my relatives (that lives in these countries) and then transfer money to my account in Iran?

Can I save my income in a US bank and then go there and get it?

What are the problems?

Comment: Evading US sanctions are a federal crime, and the US will attempt to prosecute anyone anywhere in the world for doing it or attempting to do it. That being said, you will have to read the "banking transaction" sanctions to see for yourself what the sanctions actually are, as they may only be targeted to individual companies and have broad exemptions. And if you can get a visa within countries and actually open a bank account then it'll be more likely that it is practical to compensate you.

Comment: Sanctions are on the banking industry, not on the people working for foreign companies. He is trying to find a resolution the lack of ability to get direct deposit of his earnings. When a foreign company hires someone like him, they know where he lives and what sanctions apply to them, so if they hire him, then its not evasion or illegal. But they should have some way to get the funds to him given they know banking problems won't allow direct transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should talk to a lawyer who's familiar with the matter. I'm not such a lawyer.

For the best of my understanding, at least with regards to the US, the answer to all three of your questions is **no**. Legally, a US company cannot employ Iranian residents and transfer money to Iran.

However, I know of Iranians working *in* the US. So if you manage to secure a H1b visa and move to the US - you can work and earn money here. What you do with it after you earned it - is your business.

Comment: Mod note: Post edited and comments deleted to remove editorializing and stick to the factual part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you litteadv. Can you tell me what a H1b visa is? +1 for your help

Comment: @Babak.Abad Visa are not discusses on this forum. http://www.uscis.gov/eir/visa-guide/h-1b-specialty-occupation/understanding-h-1b-requirements

Comment: @Babak.Abad they could have just called it a work visa. That's what a H1b visa is.

Comment: Well, there are different types of "work visas" in the US, H1b is the most relevant one IMHO.

Comment: Yeah but none the less, a work visa. There are different classification of H1b visa too but I didn't see you mention all of those either, so work visa would have sufficed on par with your answer.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ there's only one classification of H1b visa - H1b.